# Systematic removal of numbered values as deleting elements jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, math

I have a math coding issue. Below is a simplified version of my actual script. An order number is generated at the top based on the current date and the first order of the day appended as ".1". At the bottom is a collapsible button that contains a sample ID which should be the ordernumber.1 with an appended ".#" for each sample. So sample 5 will be ordernumber.1.5.

The problem is when deleting a sample by clicking on the delete sample button next to the sample does not reorder the sample numbers. So samples 1,2,3,4,5 and deleting 3 will then be 1,2,4,5. I need them to be 1,2,3,4 and then the same with the order numbers: ordernumber.1.5 should become ordernumber.1.4. I think some sort of "for" loop should be added in the delete button code to account for the following buttons.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var d = new Date();
  var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
  var day = d.getDate();
  var year = d.getFullYear() - 2000;
  var date = year +
    (month < 10 ? '0' : '') + month +
    (day < 10 ? '0' : '') + day;
  var order = 1
  var output = date + "." + order;
  $("#ordernumber").text(output);
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#addsmplbtn").click(function() {
    var element = $(".samplesinfo.hidden").clone(true);
    element.removeClass('hidden').insertAfter(".samplesinfo:last");
    $(".panel").slideUp();
    var n = $(".samplesinfo").length - 1;
    element.find('.samplebtn').text('Sample ' + n);
    $("#nsamples").text(n);
    var ordernumber = $("#ordernumber").text();
    var output = (ordernumber + "." + n);
    $("#sampleid").text(output);
  });

  $(".delbtn").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".samplesinfo").remove();
    var n = $(".samplesinfo").length - 1;
    $("#nsamples").text(n);
  });

  $(".samplebtn").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".panel").slideToggle();
  });
  $("#showsamples").click(function() {
    $(".panel").slideDown();
  });
  $("#hidesamples").click(function() {
    $(".panel").slideUp();
  });
  $("#alldelbtn").click(function() {
    $(".samplesinfo").remove();
  });
  $("#addsmplbtn").trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
  .hidden {
    display: none;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <div class="main_body">
    <div class="maincolumn">
      <div id="Add New Order" class="tabcontent">
        <div class="column">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="subcontainer">
              <p><b>Order Number:</b></p>
              <span id="ordernumber" class="fixedsampinfo"></span>
              <br>
              <p><b>Number of Samples:</b></p>
              <span id="nsamples" class="fixedsampinfo"></span>
              <br>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mySidenav" id="mySidenav">
          <button id="addsmplbtn">Add Additional Sample</button>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <button id="showsamples">Show All Sample Information</button>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <button id="hidesamples">Hide All Sample Information</button>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <button id="alldelbtn" class="alldelbtn">Delete All Samples</button>
        </div>
        <div id="samplesinfo" class="samplesinfo hidden">
          <button class="delbtn" style="width:50%;float:right;">Delete Sample</button>
          <button id="samplebtn" class="samplebtn" style="width:50%;">Sample</button>
          <div class="panel">
            <div class="container">
              <div id="usrInput" class="subcontainer">
                <p style="float:left;margin: 5px;"><b>Sample ID:</b></p>
                <span id="sampleid" class="fixedsampinfo"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>





</body>

</html>
```

Two other problems that, for the life of me, I cannot solve is that when clicking the "delete all samples" button, it also deletes the hidden "template", thus a new sample cannot be added. Finally the ordernumbers are only added to the second added sample with the incorrect ID, so the first sample is empty and the second is ordernumber.1.1 and should be ordernumber.1.2.

Any help would be appreciated, these issues are driving me mad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** 
Don't use any id attribute for elements inside the `samplesinfo` element. Because you reproduce this element, in this case the IDs are repeated. And as you know, the ID Attribute should be Unique.

**Do this:**

```js
$( document ).ready( function() {
  var d = new Date(),
      month = d.getMonth() + 1,
      day = d.getDate(),
      year = d.getFullYear() - 2000,
      date = year + ( month < 10 ? '0' : '' ) + month + ( day < 10 ? '0' : '' ) + day,
      order = 0,
      output = date + '.' + order;

  $( '#ordernumber' ).text( output );

  $( '#addsmplbtn' ).click(function() {
    var element = $( '.samplesinfo.hidden' ).clone( true );
    element.removeClass( 'hidden' ).insertAfter( '.samplesinfo:last' );
    order++;
    $( '.samplebtn:last' ).text( 'Sample ' + order );
    $( '.sampleid:last' ).text( output + '.' + order );
    $( '#nsamples' ).text( order );
    $( '.panel:last' ).slideUp()
  } )

  $( '.delbtn' ).click( function() {
    $( this ).closest( '.samplesinfo' ).remove();
    order--;
    $( '#nsamples' ).text( order );
    $( '.samplebtn' ).each( function( index, element ) {
      $( this ).text( 'Sample ' + index )
    } )
    $( '.sampleid' ).each( function( index, element ) {
      $( this ).text( output + '.' + index )
    } )
  } )

  $( '#alldelbtn' ).click( function() {
    $( '.samplesinfo' ).not( '.hidden' ).remove();
    order = 0;
    $( '#nsamples' ).text( order )
  } )

  $( '.samplebtn' ).click( function() { $( this ).next( '.panel' ).slideToggle() } )
  $( '#showsamples' ).click( function() { $( '.panel' ).slideDown() } )
  $( '#hidesamples' ).click( function() { $( '.panel' ).slideUp() } )
  $( '#addsmplbtn' ).trigger( 'click' )
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none
}
button {
  background-color: #86af49;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .3s;
  transition-duration: .3s
}
button:hover {
  background-color: #405d27
}
.delbtn {
  background-color: #f7786b
}
.delbtn:hover {
  background-color: #c94c4c
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main_body">
  <div class="maincolumn">
    <div id="Add New Order" class="tabcontent">
      <div class="column">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="subcontainer">
            <p><b>Order Number: </b><span id="ordernumber" class="fixedsampinfo"></span></p>
            <p><b>Number of Samples: </b><span id="nsamples" class="fixedsampinfo"></span></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mySidenav" id="mySidenav">
        <button id="addsmplbtn">Add Additional Sample</button>
        <button id="showsamples">Show All Sample Information</button>
        <button id="hidesamples">Hide All Sample Information</button>
        <button id="alldelbtn" class="alldelbtn">Delete All Samples</button>
        <br><br>
      </div>
      <div class="samplesinfo hidden">
        <button class="delbtn" style="width:50%; float: right">Delete Sample</button>
        <button class="samplebtn" style="width:50%;">Sample</button>
        <div class="panel" style="clear: right; background-color: #deeaee; padding: 5px">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="subcontainer">
              <p><b>Sample ID: </b><span class="fixedsampinfo sampleid"></span></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This was a very rookie mistake from my side.